# How to parse the future tense of "Driving on the highway, you will see a big sign"?

Tags: tense, present-participles, participle-clauses

OP"Participle clause doesn't indicate a specific tense; instead, we should look at the main clause to understand it.

> Driving on the highway, one must be careful. (present)
>   Driving on the highway, he had an accident. (past)
>   Driving on the highway, you will see a big sign. (future)"

Does the future tense part mean

> While you drive on the high way,you will see a big sign.

Comment: Please don't post parts of your question in the comments section. Also, if you need a line break, use two spaces (hit the space button two times) after the last word in the line.

Comment: And basically, yes, your reading seems correct to me. "While you drive on the highway, you will see a big sign". (highway is a single word).

Comment: Closer to the original would be: While driving on the highway, you will see a big sign.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for the most part.

Sometimes it means something will happen at some future point in time:

> Driving down Route 27 through Oxford, you will pass by Anita's Market.

or it could mean that something is inevitable, or very likely to happen:

> Crossing the desert in a caravan, you will get thirsty.

or it could address a certain need:

> Hiking up Mount Everest, you will need supplemental oxygen.

or it might ever refer to a prediction that won't necessarily come true:

> Taking the field against Liverpool on Saturday, Madrid will lose.

All of these examples are various "flavors" of the future tense.

Comment: By the way, does the second part equal"while he was driving on the highway,he had an accident" or "while he drove on the highway,he had an accident.)?? Or both are make sensen?? Is it interchangeable?

Comment: Both make sense, but I think the your first one expresses it better.